# Sorting data AngularJS / NodeJS / MongoDB

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, angularjs, mongodb

I have more than 25000 data in a collection so I have to optimize for the front-end.

First with node JS, I did a pagination for the rest API:

```
 app.get('/api', function(req, res, next) {

  Image.paginate({}, req.query.page, req.query.limit, function(err, pageCount, articles, itemCount) {

    if (err) return next(err)

    res.format({
      html: function() {
        res.status('articles').send({
          articles: articles,
          pageCount: pageCount,
          itemCount: itemCount
        })
      }
    })
  })
});app.listen(3000);
```

So i can access my data with:

```
localhost:3000/page=1&limit=5
localhost:3000/page=2&limit=5
```

...

But I would like to be able to search by id in all the JSON I have:

```
localhost:3000/id=[search by id]
```

because, in my JSON I have for each data:

```
"_id":"542e65368a1cec1227ae2bac",
"_id":"542e66b78a1cec1643e0f032",
...
```

How I can to do that?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I have too much data (+150000 ids almost) and it will be very long I think so.

Comment: If you feel that MongoDB sorting is slower, you can just hold the `id` and `time` in a data structure in memory and keep that sorted and globally accessible. Any inserts to the mongodb will also have a similar insert into the in memory sorted structure. This needs to be optimized and managed correctly for scalability, but I feel that for small websites this should suffice. EDIT. The key is that you only sort it once here as opposed to each mongodb query.